# Is "@media only ..." valid css

Tags: css, validation

Many places, I see the practice of "@media only ..." recommended in css. However, the w3c validator does not accept this. Lets take an example, from:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .gridmenu {
        width:100%;
    }

    .gridmain {
        width:100%;
    }

    .gridright {
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

If I paste this into the CSS validator, it says "unrecognized media only", also when I specify CSS3. If, however, I omit the `only` keyword, the CSS is validated. Who's right here? w3schools or w3c? And does it matter whether the `only` keyword is included?

EDIT - This is the validator I used:
http://www.css-validator.org/

Given the design, it didn't occur to me it might not be w3c's own, because it had the w3c logo and everything. I'm not sure why the genuine validator (https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) comes up in Russian in my browser, however that was the reason I didn't use it. I thought it couldn't be the "official" one.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/#mq-only

Comment: Thank you. Those who downvoted, kindly explain your downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following validator, you shouldn't run into any problems.

https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for newbie question, but why is it in russian? Or is it only on my system?

Comment: @Balthazar fine for me :) switch language at the top.

Comment: Sorry, it's extremely late here. Given that it first came up in Russian, I didn't realize it was w3c's own validator.

Comment: @Balthazar no problem! glad I could help.